# Overriding a variable retrieved from val()

Tags: jquery

In the following code, how would I go about overriding the "donateAmount" variable whenever someone initiates the click function?

In other words, whenever someone clicks it removes whatever is inside the variable "donateAmount" and replaces with the new val() amount.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

This code below now works, thanks to fixing the variable scope issue.

```
$('label input').click(function () {
    if ($('label input').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
        $('.donate-now label').not($(this).parent()).removeClass('checked');
        var donateAmount = $(".checked input").val();


     }


    $('#click').click(function(){

        if ($('label #other').is(':checked')) {
            donateAmount = $("#otherAmount").val();
        }
           $('p').html(donateAmount);

    });   
 });
```

Comment: Looks like a scope issue; remove the second `var` in front of `donateAmount`. Also have a quick read on [variable scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Comment: You can't redeclare a variable inside the same scope.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up on variable scope, I looked into it and got the code to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var donateAmount = $(".checked input").val();
$('label input').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        $this.closest('label').addClass('checked');
        $('.donate-now label').not($this.closest('label')).removeClass('checked');
        donateAmount = $this.val();
        if ($('#other').is(':checked')) {
           donateAmount = $("#otherAmount").val();
        }
    }
});

$('#otherAmount').change(function() {
    donateAmount = this.value;
});

$('#click').click(function () {
    $('p').html('$' + donateAmount);
});
```

[Check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CW5yk/)

The way you are defining the click event  `$('#click').click(function ()` will bind the event multiple times , once for every click.

So move the event outside the click event.

Also try using `.on` to bind the event handlers.

`.click(function () {`   changes to   `.on('click', function () {`

Comment: It work initially, but if you select another check box, the variable does not replace the original variable. Here it is in action, http://jsfiddle.net/YB8UW/33/